# Is it safer to use multiple RS-485 point to point connections compared to a daisy chain?

Tags: digital-communications, rs485, bus

When wiring multiple RS485 slaves to a master equipped with a RS232/RS422/RS485 interface*: is it safer to wire multiple point to point connections from the hub with their own termination resistor, compared to using one socket on the hub and daisy chaining them all terminating with a single resistor? The spec seems to say daisy chaining is a "dumb" parallel hard-wire, and I wonder if one receiver couldn't freeze the bus or even damage it (meaning the interfaces) if a failure occurs.

*: the interface is a 8 or 16 ports industrial USB to RS232/RS422/RS485 converter, to be selected

Comment: The standard is suggesting on only two termination resistors (on two ends of the bus). If you wire more, the overall resistance will drop (parallel resistors, right?) thus consuming more current from your transceivers, up to the point where they won't be able to push it. And, as for me, daisy chaining is much cleaner way to wire a bus.

Comment: Its unclear from your question whether your 'hub' would be a star-topology network with all of the nodes still directly connected together, or an intelligent device with multiple RS485 ports and repeating data between them.

Comment: If one of the slaves will behave incorrectly (transmitting on the bus, when it shouldn't) the popology won't help, unless the "hub" is something intelligent and capable of detecting such conditions.

Comment: Since each port of the "hub" can be a RS232 port, I would assume all lines are independent - given that RS232 is only point to point. Does that mean that it is indeed safer not to daisy chain them on one port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you drive the chips in parallel or series, it's possible for a single failure (an input failing short) to disable the entire network.

Worse, if you build a star topology (a central hub with transmission lines radiating out to separate ICs) with each receiver having its own terminating resistor, the network will not work at all. Let's say that your connecting conductors have a characteristic impedance of 100 ohms. Putting a 100 ohm resistor at each end of a daisy chain will produce a DC load on your hub of 50 ohms (100/2). For a 2-volt swing on the bus, a load current of 40 mA (2 / 50) is required, and the hub is certainly capable of producing this, as are the trancscievers at each station. If you have 10 stations, you'll need 10 resistors, and the overall total load resistance is 10 ohms (100/10). The current needed by the hub to give 2 volts will be 200 mA (2 / 10) and I can pretty much guarantee that the hub won't do it. Not only that, but each of the bus stations need to do the same, and THEY won't manage it either.

Comment: Excellent point, thanks. I'm not sure I get the last sentence though, it sounds like each station has to provide 200mA but they only need to drive their own bus (100Ohm impedance) don't they?